# Log4j log level for a specific message

Tags: java, log4j

A 3rd party library that I am importing is ouputting a `DEBUG` level log message that I would like log.
Normally, I only log `INFO` messages.
If I set my log4j2.xml to "debug" for this specific package, then I get extremely noisy logging.

Is there a way in which I can setup my log4j xml logger to output only this specific `method's` log message? (I cannot change this library's code, only the configuration)

```
<Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="APPLICATION"/>
        </Root>
        
        <Logger
            name="com.some.library.i.cannot.change" level="debug">
    CAN I ADD SOMETHING HERE THAT WILL ONLY LOG 1 METHOD'S specific message?
            <AppenderRef ref="APPLICATION"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
```

Code from the library looks something like this

```
    void oneMethodInLibrary(){
                     // I want to log this message
                     LOG.debug("Loaded Configuration {}", config);
    }

    void otherMethodInLibrary(){
                     LOG.debug("Other noisy debug message I don't need {}", data);
    }
```

Comment: Why not use trace instead of debug in second method?

Comment: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html

Comment: @user7294900 The code is not mine. I cannot change it, I am only consuming it. I cannot change the log level in the code.